# Binary search doesn't return anything

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I'm trying to run a binary search where the user can input a value and my binary search method will return a part number and price but it doesn't return anything when any value is entered. The search is used on parallel arrays. I call the method below in main.

```
public int binSearch(int target)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = numCount -1;
    boolean found = false;


    while(first <= last && !found)
    {
        mid = (first + last)/2;
        if(partNum[mid]==target)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else if(partNum[mid]<target)
        {
            first = mid +1;
        }
        else if(partNum[mid]>target)
        {
            last = mid -1;
        }
        else if(!found)
        {
            mid = -1;
        }
        return mid;
    }
```

Here is the code that calls the method in the main class.

```
index = inputDevice.nextInt();
while(inventoryArray.binSearch(index) >= 0);
{
System.out.printf("Binary search found part #%d. The price is $%d\n", index, inventoryArray.binSearch(index));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is supposed to be sorted.

You need to set the return outside the loop
and when the last condition is reached ( which is supposed to mean that the target is not in the sorted array) you should break after setting mid = -1 , and no need to check if its found

```
  while(first <= last && !found)
   {
    mid = (first + last)/2;
    if(partNum[mid]==target)
    {
        found = true;
    }
    else if(partNum[mid]<target)
    {
        first = mid +1;
    }
    else if(partNum[mid]>target)
    {
        last = mid -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        mid = -1;
        break;
    }
  }
  return mid;
```

Comment: the file for the array already came sorted. I updated the return and added the break but it still won't return anything. Do you want me to include more info about my main class and array class?

Comment: Yes please that would be helpful

Comment: I just set it to return -1 and the program compiled fine after that. I think It's something about returning mid.